# Visual Studio 2010 Doc Format Not working

Tags: visual-studio-2010

For a new installation of VS 2010 (after a hard disk change) the Document format function does not work.  When I try to format I get

"The key combination (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D) is bound to command (Format Document) which is not currently available"

How do I make it available?

Comment: what kind of document are you viewing, and in what view, if applicable?

Comment: I'm viewing a Arduino PDE (which is C++).  I saved it as a CPP and still got the same error message.

Comment: I also opened up a standard C++ solution and it has the same problem.  I have come to depend on source code formatting as a major tool in debugging and miss it a lot...

Comment: No one seems to have an answer for this one.  I give up.  I downloaded VS 2012 and it works fine.  I would rather use VS 2010 because of the hate I have for that 'Metro' design in 2012...

Comment: Sorry; no idea what could cause it to stop doing that :(  I think 2012 will grow on you after a while, though :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Tools` menu at the top of the screen in VS2010, you can go to `Options -> Environment -> Keyboard` or `Customize -> Commands -> Keyboard` to modify keyboard shortcuts and make sure that the keybinding for document formatting is still there.